# Print the error and continue the while loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to build a stored procedure that checks if there are some duplicates in all the tables. The name of the key in each table is built through the name of the table plus the word 'Key'. For example, if the table name is 'FactSalesOrder' the corresponding key is SalesOrderKey. So, with the help of a cursor, one can check each table. I want to raise an error if there is no consistency between the table and the key. Even if the error is printed with the name of table (in this way one can easily fix the error) I want the while loop continues. The following is my code I want change in view of the previous discussion.

```
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
  BEGIN

DECLARE @campo VARCHAR(100) = NULL

IF @table like 'Dim%'
    SET @campo = SUBSTRING(@table, 4, len(@table))+'Key'
IF @table like 'Fact%'
    SET @campo = SUBSTRING(@table, 5, len(@table))+'Key'

IF NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table
     and COLUMN_NAME = @campo
     and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dev_dwh'
) BEGIN RAISERROR ('Error: the key of the following table is not consistency:', 16,6) PRINT @table BREAK; END


SET @sqlCommand = 
'INSERT INTO #BaseData (TableName, KeyValue, KeyValueCount)
 SELECT  '''+ @table+ ''' AS TableHere, '+@campo +', COUNT('+ @campo +') AS COUNTVALUE '+ 
'FROM [dev_dwh].[' + @table + '] GROUP BY '+@campo
EXEC (@sqlCommand)

FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor into @table

END
```

Comment: fetcvherror will alweay stop everything, you need anothe rmethod to gather errors

Comment: ok, thank you. Which method can I use?

Comment: @SMor nope, we are not using them.

Comment: `RAISERROR ... WITH NOWAIT` should work.  It's not awesome, SQL Server is not meant for this type of output.  But I've used that before to do similar things.  You should read the docs carefully, especially the warning about it not honoring `XACT_ABORT`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @squillman thank you. So you mean I have replace BREAK with WITH NOWAIT ?

Comment: You don't really check for duplicates. You at least need a HAVING clause in your WHERE clause to avoid all the rows that have a count of 1 (unless you enjoy scrolling through many rows of "OK" values). And it seems to me that you can gather all of the inconsistent naming problems in a single query and dump those somewhere without throwing errors while also avoiding those rows in your cursor.

Comment: No, it's part of the `RAISERROR` statement.  Replacing `BREAK` with `WITH NOWAIT` would be invalid syntax.  Read the link I posted.  But also pay attention to what @SMor is telling you.  That's going to help you more here.

Comment: @SMor, thank you. For the first argument you said: the code continues. There is a part of code that I didn't write here where I have the HAVING clause. For the second argument: ok, I will try, but I would like not change the "body" of the code.